# Window.scrollTo(0, 1) To hide address bar not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the window.scrollTo(0,1) trick to minimise the addressbar on mobile. 
I am having issues with getting it to work, I think this is because of way I have chosen to arrange my elements.

Currently my page is laid out as follows:

```css
#everything {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#menu{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 5vw;
  position: absolute;
}
#content {
  height 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
}

#header {
  height: 15vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
}

#site-body {
  height: 85vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="everything">
    <div id="menu">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="header">
      </div>
      <div id="site-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The site-body contains overflow content set to scroll.

None of the elements are greater than `100vh` in `height`, so scrolling down the
page isn't possible.

When I change `everything` to have a `height` of `150vh`, I am able to trigger the 
minimised browser addressbar but ONLY if I initiate the scroll-down with my finger over
the `header` element. The `window.scrollTo()` still wont work though.

I want the page to load on mobile, and then I want to run window.scrollTo(0,1) in JS 
to trigger the 'minimised address bar' browser feature. I am quite confused.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. It would be huge security risk if websites would be able to just hide the address bar.